# Preloading dynamically loaded images with jquery

Tags: jquery, preload

These images are loaded dynamically:

```
<div id="gallery-images" class="gallery-control">
    <ul>
        <img class="galleryImgs" data-src="images/test-image-1.jpg" src="images/test-image-1-s.jpg" />
        <img class="galleryImgs" data-src="images/test-image-2.jpg" src="images/test-image-2-s.jpg" />
        <img class="galleryImgs" data-src="images/test-image-3.jpg" src="images/test-image-3-s.jpg" />      
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to preload the images URL's from the "data-src" attribute of each img tag. This is the code I have written:

```
$('.galleryImgs').each(function(){
    $('<img/>')[0].src = $(this).attr("data-src");
});
```

Can't run the dynamic script at the moment so the image tags are currently static. Does this code look as though it should work or am I missing anything?

Comment: Check if it triggers any GET request for those images on your console. If not, you can try appending it to the DOM inside a `display:none` container.

Comment: I would use each function like this:

    $('.galleryImgs').each(function(idx, e) {
        ...
    }

Comment: So is that not working? The code looks fine. I can't tell if you;re having an actual issue or just asking if it looks ok.

Comment: can't actually tell if it's working because as i said everything is static right now, but after clearing the cache the performance transitions seems to have improved but obviously i can't be entirely sure until I run the actual dynamic script. If anything I will use the suggestion provided by @FabrícioMatté and view the updated ajax source to ensure it works.

Comment: Oh that was just a quick thought, anyway, using a `$.get` to pre-cache each image should work in modern browsers too. I might make a fiddle to test.

Comment: would be much appreciated if you did.

Comment: Yeah, I said "might" because I'm a little busy tonight, but I'll put it up to test in a couple minutes. `:P`

Comment: The issue with `$.get` is that you wouldn't be able to pre-load cross-domain pics though.

Comment: cross-domain wont be an issue as everything is being pulled from the same domain the script is being run on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a quick snippet with my initial comment's idea, which should work cross-domain or not:

```
$(function() {
    //creates an imgcacher hidden element
    $('<div/>', {id: 'imgcacher', style: 'display:none;'}).appendTo('body');
    var cacher = $('#imgcacher'); //caches the cacher selector

    //appends the images to the DOM for caching
    $('.galleryImgs').each(function(){
        $('<img/>', {src: $(this).data('src'), class: "precachedImg"}).appendTo(cacher);
    });

    //clean up the DOM after the images are fully loaded and cached
    $('.precachedImg').promise().done(function() {
        cacher.remove();
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/gB8FV/3/)
Note that the 2nd image may be slightly too large to load in 5 seconds if your connection is not fast enough, but it should be at least partially loaded then.

`$.get` didn't work for caching the images on Chrome when I tested it, thus the solution above is my preferred. It works nicely on all browsers I've tested at any connection speed and file size. Modern browsers will only request the image resource once and display it in parallel with all other dupes in the page, without generating extra requests as an ajax request would.

Also, it's a dynamic, scalable and clean solution. If you prefer simplicity though, it has the "same" end-user experience than just adding the images with `display:none` to the DOM initially. Obviously that clutters up the DOM unnecessarily, hence I'd go with my snippet above.

Also, here's a slightly simplified version:

```
$(function() {
    //appends the images to the DOM for caching
    $('.galleryImgs').each(function(){
        $('<img/>', {src: $(this).data('src'), class: 'precachedImg', style: 'display:none;'}).appendTo('body');
    });

    //clean up the DOM as the images are loaded and cached
    $('.precachedImg').load(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/gB8FV/7/)

Comment: No problem. `=]` I just made a slightly simplified version as well, which ensures that the image is fully loaded before removing the element from the DOM if you ever run into problems with the first code (shouldn't happen in any modern browser though), or, you can also erase the clean-up block as well if you find problems with any browser.